# Radio Buttons Displaying Incorrectly using Bootstrap in ruby on rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, forms, twitter-bootstrap, activerecord

Hi I'm a new programmer and I'm trying to make a somewhat complex form. Im using bootstrap 3 and ruby on rails 4. I have a form for making a unit(a kind of product) that have a color. You can pick this color from the model Color using nested attributes. I only want the user to be able to select the hue of the colour using radio buttons with values from 0-9 or n or s. I want all this radio buttons to be in the same line but I having some problems with the styling. I can only make them all vertical or all horizontal but all overlapping and with all the labels behind the radio_buttons. I have no idea how to fix this :( any info would be welcome.
Thanks in advance.
[image]

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_for(@unit) do |f| %>

    <%= f.label :quantity, "Cantidad:" %>
    <%= f.number_field :quantity, class: 'form-control' %>
    <hr>
...

  <div class="radio-inline">
    <%= f.fields_for :colors do |ff| %>
      <%= ff.label :hue, "Nombre de tu Marca:" %>
      <%= ff.radio_button :hue, '0' %> 0
      <%= ff.radio_button :hue, '1' %> 1
      <%= ff.radio_button :hue, '2' %> 2
      <%= ff.radio_button :hue, '3' %> 3
      <%= ff.radio_button :hue, '4' %> 4
      <%= ff.radio_button :hue, '5' %> 5
      <%= ff.radio_button :hue, '6' %> 6
      <%= ff.radio_button :hue, '7' %> 7
      <%= ff.radio_button :hue, '8' %> 8
      <%= ff.radio_button :hue, '9' %> 9
      <%= ff.radio_button :hue, 'n' %> n
      <%= ff.radio_button :hue, 's' %> s
    <% end %>
  </div>
....
 </div>
</div>
```

I also did this whit no results:

```
<%= f.fields_for :colors do |ff| %>
      <%= ff.label :hue, "Hue:" %>
      <div class='radio_inline'><%= ff.radio_button :hue, '0' %> 0</div>
      <div class='radio_inline'><%= ff.radio_button :hue, '1' %> 1</div>
      <div class='radio_inline'><%= ff.radio_button :hue, '2' %> 2</div>
      <div class='radio_inline'><%= ff.radio_button :hue, '3' %> 3</div>
      <div class='radio_inline'><%= ff.radio_button :hue, '4' %> 4</div>
      <div class='radio_inline'><%= ff.radio_button :hue, '5' %> 5</div>
      <div class='radio_inline'><%= ff.radio_button :hue, '6' %> 6</div>
      <div class='radio_inline'><%= ff.radio_button :hue, '7' %> 7</div>
      <div class='radio_inline'><%= ff.radio_button :hue, '8' %> 8</div>
      <div class='radio_inline'><%= ff.radio_button :hue, '9' %> 9</div>
      <div class='radio_inline'><%= ff.radio_button :hue, 'n' %> n</div>
      <div class='radio_inline'><%= ff.radio_button :hue, 's' %> s</div>
    <% end %>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try wrapping each radio_button with a label tag with class of 'radio-inline', as shown in this bootstrap example, from the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms):

```
<label class="radio-inline">
  <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1"   value="option1"> 1
</label>
```

In your case, you shouldn't wrap the whole nested form in a radio-inline div. Instead wrap each radio button input in a radio-inline div, like so:

```
<%= f.fields_for :colors do |ff| %>
  <%= ff.label :hue, "Nombre de tu Marca:" %>
  <div class="radio-inline">
    <%= ff.radio_button :hue, '0' %> 0
  </div>
  <div class="radio-inline">
    <%= ff.radio_button :hue, '1' %> 1
  </div>
  <div class="radio-inline">
    <%= ff.radio_button :hue, '2' %> 2
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried that but I'm not sure how to implement it with ruby on rails form helper. Do you know how I should do it?

Comment: Thanks man, I just tried your solution but It now working yet, see edited question

Comment: you have 'radio_line' in your edited question.  It shouldn't be underscore, it should be hyphen, 'radio-inline'

Comment: That Fixed my error! Sorry what a dumb mistake! Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You could also try to add `:item_wrapper_class => 'inline'` to your code.

So for example a line of your code would look like `<%= ff.radio_button, { :item_wrapper_class => 'inline' }, :hue, '6' %> 6`